# let a,b,c be the sides of a triangle and $a+b+c=2$ then prove that $ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 +2abc < 2$

Tags: inequality

let a,b,c be the sides of a triangle and $a+b+c=2$ then prove that
 $ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 +2abc < 2$

I used the fact that $   a+b-c>0  $ and multiplied the 3 cyclic equations but coudn't reach the final equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just continue your approach, focusing on reaching the goal: 
$$(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b) > 0 \iff (1-c)(1-a)(1-b) > 0 $$
$$\iff 1-(a+b+c)+(ab+bc+ca)-abc > 0$$
$$\iff 1-(2)+\tfrac12 \left((a+b+c)^2-a^2-b^2-c^2 \right)-abc > 0$$
$$\iff -2+ \left(4-a^2-b^2-c^2 \right)-2abc > 0$$
$$\iff a^2+b^2+c^2 + 2abc < 2$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's homogenize the equation by multiplying with $ a+ b + c = 2$.

We need to show that

$$ 2 ( a + b + c) (a^2 + b^2 + c^2) + 8abc < (a+b+c)^3.$$

Expanding this, it is equivalent to showing that

$$ (a+b-c) ( b+c-a) ( c+a-b) > 0. $$

Hence we are done.